# Как правильно писать предлог в предложении "по информации, полученной (у/из) администрации школы"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно писать предлог в данном предложении?

> По информации, полученной у администрации школы

или

> По информации, полученной из администрации школы

(информация получена в разговоре с директором учреждения образования по телефону)

Answer (score 1):

Если информацию выпрашивать или получать путем отъема, то лучше других подойдет предлог «у». Но такое трудно представить в отношениях с администрацией школы.
Предлог «из» будет хорош, когда подразумевается добыча или извлечение информации. К примеру: «По информации, полученной из архива администрации школы».
Если информация получена без усилий, в качестве распоряжения (если хотите, - подарка), то используйте предлог «от». Например: «По информации, полученной от администрации школы».